# Loop incrementation for url

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xquery

I want to insert dynamic url from my title, it works but it displays 6*6 'cause of 2 differents loops... I don't know how to do differently...

I tried to use global variable but it's the same... (I have 6 Recipes)

Thanks !

Code XML :

```
  <recette id="r1">
    <titre>Cake au chocolat</titre>
    <cat>dessert</cat>
    <type/>
    <nombre>6</nombre>
    <listeingredients>
      <ingredient q="150" u="g">chocolat pâtissier</ingredient>
      <ingredient q="3" u="pièce">oeufs</ingredient>
      <ingredient q="100" u="g">sucre en poudre</ingredient>
      <ingredient q="60" u="g">farine</ingredient>
      <ingredient q="1" u="cuillère à café">levure</ingredient>
      <ingredient q="80" u="g">beurre</ingredient>
      <ingredient q="50" u="g">poudre d'amandes</ingredient>
    </listeingredients>
    <cuisson>
      <temps type="preparation">15</temps>
      <temps type="cuisson">30</temps>
      <temperature u="C">180</temperature>
    </cuisson>
  </recette>
  <recette id="r2">
    <titre>Brownies aux noix de pécan</titre>
    <cat>dessert</cat>
    <type/>
    <nombre>6</nombre>
    <listeingredients>
      <ingredient q="200" u="g">chocolat à cuire</ingredient>
    <cuisson>
      <temps type="preparation">10</temps>
      <temps type="cuisson">25</temps>
      <temperature u="C">180</temperature>
    </cuisson>
    <instruction>
      <etape>Faire fondre le chocolat avec le beurre, soit au bain-marie à feu doux, soit au micro-ondes sur programme 'décongélation'.</etape>
      <etape>Quand c'est bien fondu, mélanger et ajouter le sucre, les oeufs un par un, la farine, puis les noix de pécan hachées grossièrement.</etape>
      <etape>Bien mélanger et verser dans un moule carré de 20 cm (ou rectangulaire pas trop grand), chemisé de papier sulfurisé.</etape>
      <etape>Mettre au four préchauffé à 180°C pendant 25 min.</etape>
      <etape>Laisser refroidir et couper en carrés.</etape>
    </instruction>
  </recette>
</listerecettes>
```

Code xq :

```
{
    for $titre in db:open("recettes")//recette//titre, $j in (6,2,1,5,4,3)
    order by $titre
    return
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8984/rest/recettes?query=//recette[@id='r{$j}']">
        <ul>
            <li>
            {
                $titre
            }
            </li>
        </ul>
    </a>
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Given your query and the two loops it should return 36 elements with 6 entries. I don't really know what $j is supposed to do. Do you want to use it to construct the link? If so,  I don't know why as the id element is already in your element, so why not use this?

Comment: $j contains the number of my recipes (r1 --> Recipes 1) , (r2 --> Recipes 2 .. etc). I don't want to show 36 elements but only 6 ! with the different url According to the recipes !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment I still don't really know what you want to achieve with `$j` as it is not useful at all and can simply be removed. So I guess you maybe want something else and not just a simple list ordered by thte title - If so, please clearify what you want to achieve. Otherwise, simply removing the `$j` and using the id attribute will work fine.

```
for $recette in db:open("recettes")//recette
let $titre := $recette/titre
order by $titre
return
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8984/rest/recettes?query=//recette[@id='{$recette/@id}']">
    <ul>
        <li>
        {
            $titre
        }
        </li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

Comment: It works but my stylesheet is not taken by Firefox in my opinion it's 'cause i do a query.. but it's a real problem.. do you have any ideas? thanks

Comment: When i tried to clic to show differents recipes my css is not included, but when i open my file "recettes.xml" (which i insert a <xml stylesheet../>) it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but I had just found an other way ! :

```
for $titre in db:open("recettes")//recette//titre
order by $titre
return
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8984/rest/recettes?query=//recette[@id='{$titre/..//@id}']">
    <ul>
        <li>
        {
          $titre
        }
        </li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

I tested your code and it's correct but you've forget "$titre" after order by !

Comment: You are right, I just edited it.
Please note, that your XQuery is not very fast. // steps should be avoided, as the whole subtree has to be searched for this. Here you especially don't need this as you know for example where the id attribute is located, a simple axis step (i.e. /) is good enough.